# Get rid of [Precognitive] badge

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, badges

I can't help but wonder why the "Precognitive" badge even exists on SF. After all, it's not actually possible to qualify for it. It should be destroyed.

Comment: seems to be [status-bydesign]  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71712/should-the-precognitive-badge-be-listed-in-the-list-of-sofu-badges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Status: Broken by Design

In order to maintain a more consistent code base between sites they all have that badge even though it's impossible to get on any of the trilogy sites.

Comment: They actually said at one stage that they're also keeping it as a way just to annoy badge whores :p

Comment: It seems rather appropriate that the very concept of "broken by design" comes from the devs.